# При выполнении функции с tkinter gui окно gui виснет. Можно ли убрать данное зависание без использования threads?

Tags: python, tkinter, threading

Дело в том, что в моем tkinter gui работает функция с использованием render из requests-html. Я пытался запустить свой код и с обычной HTMLSession и с AsyncHTMLSession. При первом случае я получаю ошибку: There is no current event loop in thread; при втором: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter. Как мне заставить мою программу не зависать при выполнении функции если render можно использовать только в mainthread

Comment: Или отдельный поток, или асинхронность, но тогда нужно делать обертку для tkinter, чтобы мог работать и его цикл (mainloop), и цикл обработки событий asyncio. Я делал модуль для этого: https://pypi.org/project/async-tkinter-loop/. Пример асинхронного выполнения HTTP запроса: https://github.com/insolor/async-tkinter-loop/blob/main/examples/download_html.py

Comment: * чтобы одновременно мог работать и цикл обработки событий (eventloop) asyncio, и обрабатывались события tkinter.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сделать с помощью вашего модуля.